# Why can't I install a package despite Laravel version matching the package requirements?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install this package https://github.com/shawnsandy/img-fly on Laravel 6.5.2

According to their composer.json, they allow to use Laravel 6.* version :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "illuminate/support": "5.*|6.*",
    "league/glide-laravel": "1.*"
},
```

But on a fresh Laravel 6.5.2 version, I got this error :

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for shawnsandy/img-fly ^0.1.21 -> satisfiable by shawnsandy/img-fly[v0.1.21].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.1
    - shawnsandy/img-fly v0.1.21 requires illuminate/support 5.*
```

Is there anything I can do here ?

Comment: The library looks abandoned. Personally I'd recommend finding an alternative

Comment: Yes, but after some tries, this one is still the most simple to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the "master" branch, which [might indeed have declared support for Laravel 6](https://github.com/shawnsandy/img-fly/blob/c314fc34b75b1be59abee8407473d86a92a46ca4/composer.json#L8).

But the latest tagged version is 1.21, which [has not](https://github.com/shawnsandy/img-fly/blob/b49c7eb82e187caf4f850b3e9a6f50fe84679523/composer.json#L8). If you check the package on Packagist, you'll see [that's what you get](https://packagist.org/packages/shawnsandy/img-fly#v0.1.21).

If you are feeling brave and want to install pre-release software, you could require`the`dev-master` version, which has the Laravel support you want.

```
composer require shawnsandy/img-fly:dev-master
```

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad I missreaded versions. Let's be brave, I will try it, Laravel 6 has no major differences, I saw many packages just add the support in their requirements without changing code

Comment: Awesome. It will probably go fine.